# How to add time constraints in jsprit?

Tags: algorithm, jsprit

> setTimeWindow(new TimeWindow(start_time, end_time))

Is used to add time constraints for a task/shipment. But I want to have a complete example.
Is there any complete example of jsprit on time bound shipment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set pickup and delivery time windows of shipments this way:

`Shipment shipment = Shipment.Builder.newInstance("1")
.addSizeDimension(0,1)
.setPickupLocation(Location.newInstance(5,7))
.setPickupTimeWindow(TimeWindow.newInstance(0,1200))
.setDeliveryLocation(Location.newInstance(6,9))
.setDeliveryTimeWindow(TimeWindow.newInstance(2000,4000))
.build();`

Comment: Thanks @Stefan.
But is there is any example given in jsprit website.