# Understanding JSprit VRP constraints

Tags: jsprit

I am faced with some real-world VRP optimization problems and would like to kick the tires of jsprit.  I have a set of jobs with associated skill constraints; a set of users to service those jobs with skill constraints and time windows; and lat-lon based coordinates on all of the above.

I have been running some examples like the [VRPWithBackhaulsExample](https://github.com/graphhopper/jsprit/blob/master/jsprit-examples/src/main/java/com/graphhopper/jsprit/examples/VRPWithBackhaulsExample.java), so I can see that I need to set up a set of ConstraintManagers but I am having trouble mapping my domain to jsprit concepts in these areas:

- How do I express lat-lons in terms of JSprit inputs?  It seems like the examples use points in two-dimensional space.  It appears that I need to use VehicleRoutingTransportCosts, but I am unclear on how to do that.
- Are there examples of using time windows in non-delivery models?  I am aware of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080600/how-to-add-time-constraints-in-jsprit), but it does not seem like the same model as what I describe above.

I'm just looking to get pointed in the right direction, any guidance welcome.

Answer (score 3):

> How do I express lat-lons in terms of JSprit inputs?

You can use normal lat/long (e.g. `51.5287718, -0.2416806`) inputs. Jsprit uses a Euclidean distance calculator if a distance matrix is not set explicitly. See the [code here](https://github.com/graphhopper/jsprit/blob/7590be97948da47eefed61413c27f2a70b6ff434/jsprit-core/src/main/java/com/graphhopper/jsprit/core/problem/VehicleRoutingProblem.java#L434) and [here](https://github.com/graphhopper/jsprit/blob/7590be97948da47eefed61413c27f2a70b6ff434/jsprit-core/src/main/java/com/graphhopper/jsprit/core/util/CrowFlyCosts.java#L83).

Besides the default Euclidean distance calculator, they also have a [Great Circle Distance/Costs Calculator](https://github.com/graphhopper/jsprit/blob/master/jsprit-core/src/main/java/com/graphhopper/jsprit/core/util/GreatCircleCosts.java) which uses the [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula). You just need to call .setRoutingCost(new GreatCircleCosts()) before you build the problem, see [here](https://github.com/graphhopper/jsprit/blob/master/jsprit-core/src/test/java/com/graphhopper/jsprit/core/algorithm/OpenRoutesTest.java#L154).

If you need road distances then you'll have to generate a distance matrix yourself. You can use something like [Google Maps Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/) or [Graphhopper Matrix API](https://graphhopper.com/api/1/docs/matrix/) (We currently use the latter because of Google Maps API license restrictions) e.g. you could extend the `AbstractForwardVehicleRoutingTransportCosts` class, make API calls to a distance matrix service and then do something like `vrpBuilder.setRoutingCost(instanceOfYourCustomDistanceMatrix)`

[Open Door Logistics (ODL) Studio](http://www.opendoorlogistics.com/software/odl-studio/) works well for this type of thing if you don't want to work at the Java level. Look at the [Vehicle Routing and Scheduling Tutorial](http://www.opendoorlogistics.com/tutorials/tutorial-v-vehicle-routing-scheduling/) to see how ODL can build the distance matrix using Graphhopper for you.

> Are there examples of using time windows in non-delivery models?

Not sure what you are asking but time windows are honoured for service jobs too.

Shameless plug: you can use our web app at [intelligentrouting.io](https://intelligentrouting.io) if you don't want to write any Java and don't feel like setting up ODL.